# I get error when try go to backend after to install refinerycms-portfolio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms, portfolio

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Refinery::Authentication::Devise::Admin::Users#index

This problem appear after install refinerycms-portfolio extension.

I  have installed ruby 2.1.5, refinerycms 3.0.0 and rails 4.2.4, this is my gemfile:

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'refinerycms-portfolio', github: 'refinery/refinerycms-portfolio', branch: 'master'

    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
    group :development, :test do
      gem 'pg'
    end
    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

    # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
    gem 'turbolinks'
    # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

    # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

    # Use Unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Use Capistrano for deployment
    # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

    group :development, :test do
      # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
      gem 'byebug'
    end

    group :development do
      # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using  in views
      gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
    end

    # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
    gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

    gem 'refinerycms', git: 'https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms', branch: 'master'

    gem 'quiet_assets', group: :development

    # Add support for searching inside Refinery's admin interface.
    gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed', ['~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.0']

    # Add support for Refinery's custom fork of the visual editor WYMeditor.
    gem 'refinerycms-wymeditor', ['~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.6']

    # The default authentication adapter
    gem 'refinerycms-authentication-devise', '~> 1.0'
```

When I press "Switch to your website editor" and go to "http://localhost:3000/refinery/users" get the error,but is just with that tab option ("users").

Error:

```
    ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Refinery::Authentication::Devise::Admin::Users#index
    Showing C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-0a37f8090278/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_menu_item.html.erb where line #1 raised:

    No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"refinery/refinery/portfolio/admin/galleries", :locale=>:en}
    Trace of template inclusion: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-0a37f8090278/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_menu.html.erb, C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-0a37f8090278/core/app/views/layouts/refinery/admin.html.erb

    Rails.root: C:/Users/Alejandro/Documents/desarrollo/blog

    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:46:in `generate'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:729:in `generate'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:760:in `generate'
    routing-filter (0.5.1) lib/routing_filter/adapters/rails.rb:30:in `block in generate_with_filtering'
    refinerycms-i18n (3.0.1) lib/refinery/i18n-filter.rb:25:in `around_generate'
    routing-filter (0.5.1) lib/routing_filter/filter.rb:11:in `run'
    routing-filter (0.5.1) lib/routing_filter/chain.rb:15:in `run'
    routing-filter (0.5.1) lib/routing_filter/adapters/rails.rb:29:in `generate_with_filtering'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:803:in `url_for'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:156:in `url_for'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-0a37f8090278/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_menu_item.html.erb:1:in `_____ails_nstaller__uby______lib_ruby_gems_______bundler_gems_refinerycms__a__f________core_app_views_refinery_admin__menu_item_html_erb__267236875_54712164'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:436:in `block in collection_with_template'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:432:in `map'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:432:in `collection_with_template'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:324:in `render_collection'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `block in render'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:305:in `render'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-0a37f8090278/core/app/views/refinery/admin/_menu.html.erb:2:in `_____ails_nstaller__uby______lib_ruby_gems_______bundler_gems_refinerycms__a__f________core_app_views_refinery_admin__menu_html_erb__880856653_54829116'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/refinerycms-0a37f8090278/core/app/views/layouts/refinery/admin.html.erb:10:in `_____ails_nstaller__uby______lib_ruby_gems_______bundler_gems_refinerycms__a__f________core_app_views_layouts_refinery_admin_html_erb___1040480465_77272008'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
    activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
    actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
    railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
    railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
    dragonfly (1.0.12) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
    dragonfly (1.0.12) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
    activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
    activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
    activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
    web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    dragonfly (1.0.12) lib/dragonfly/cookie_monster.rb:9:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
    Request

    Parameters:

    {"locale"=>:en}
    Toggle session dump
    Toggle env dump
    Response

    Headers:

    None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it. It was a coding error in github project and now one contributor fix it.